# how do i place an element X, to the left of another element Y, if it comes after element Y in the HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has a display of flex, now I have two containers inside this div.
I want to place the second container to the left of the first one, but the second one comes below in the HTML.

I also want to make it so that, if the size of the first container increases, (due to longer text), it should also push the second container to the left.
I've tried using float, but it is ignored due to using display flex. I tried using `margin-left:auto` but no result, same with margin-right auto.

https://jsfiddle.net/puz1qf7v/2/

```css
.main {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.second {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: crimson;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="first">
    skyblue yabadabadoo
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    crimson yabadabadoo
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you have a flex parent div, you could always use reverse to change the order of all your elements (and justify-content to float them to the left):

```css
.main {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.first {
    min-height: 40px;
    height: fit-content;
    background-color: skyblue;
    margin: 10px;
}

.second {
    min-height: 40px;
    height: fit-content;
    background-color: crimson;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="first">
      skyblue yabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadooyabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadoo
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      crimson yabadabadoo yabadabadoo yabadabadoo
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to change the order

```css
.main {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.second {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: crimson;
  margin: 10px;
  order:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="first">
    skyblue yabadabadoo
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    crimson yabadabadoo
  </div>
</div>
```

`order: -1;` here means reverse the order.

It's convenient if you have only 2 containers, for more than 2 containers you can also use `0`, `1`, `2`... to set the order by yourself.